# How to Do If option is found on 1st Try Command & Tell dont go to 2nd Try Command PYTHON-SELENIUM?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation-testing

I have done a Script on **Python Selenium** using TRY Commands & IF ELSE.
Now i have added 3 TRY Commands and at the Second TRY i have done to find the option.

The Question is:
How to do that if **option** is found on **Second TRY Command**, dont excecute other TRY Commands & press Directly the button to go to next page?[Code Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIJma.png)

Comment: Can you post your code trials.

Comment: I just Edited the Question it is atached the Code There

Comment: So i have 3 try commands and at second try option is found and i want to not go any further and select option from second try and third try to not excecute

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.